# Наречие "только" и его синтаксические связи

Tags: синтаксис, словосочетания, наречия

***Только*** шеф приходит раньше всех.

*И **только** поздно вечером в деревню прибрели.*

Укажите, к какому слову в двух предложениях относится наречие "только", и подскажите, на какой вопрос это наречие отвечает. Мне не понятно, "только шеф" или "приходит только"? Или "приходит только шеф"? Но грамматическая основа ведь не является словосочетанием.

И ещё подскажите с синтаксическим разбором в первом предложении: "только" — обстоятельство или часть подлежащего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Большой толковый словарь](http://m.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE&all=x) говорит, что слово *только* может быть:
- частицей
- союзом
- наречием

У Вас в предложениях частица. Частица на вопросы не отвечает.

> Единственно, исключительно. Говорил т. о любви. Стремится т. к победе. Не любит т. вранья. Т. в деревне и отдыхаю. Люблю т. тебя. Не купил лишь т. из жадности.

Только шеф, только поздно вечером.

Comment: А при синтаксическом разборе оно входит в состав члена предложения, к которому относится, т. е. к подлежащему и к обстоятельству?

Comment: Думаю, да, но не уверен, такие тонкости надо у учителей спрашивать.

Comment: Частица входит в состав члена предложения, к которому относится.

Comment: Во втором предложении значение не «единственно, исключительно», а «не ранее чем» — взято из указанного вами словаря. Дополните ответ для точности.